# Typing a Phonetic Long i without a Dot

Tags: symbols, typography

I would like to type the long i as illustrated in the name "Heli":

[image]

However, the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\textbf{\={i}}
\end{document}
```

does not produce the desired typographical effect; but rather,

[image]

QUESTION: How may I type the long-*i*, as indicated above so that no dot appears in the *i*?

Comment: `\textbf{ī} ` works

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply use ī U+012B directly?

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has been quite conservative in the past as regards to defining more and more commands, because of memory constraints.

Recently, many more combinations have been defined to ease input, but not `\=i` to remove the tittle.

You could input `\={\i}`, but this is awkward. Alternatively, add the appropriate definition or use direct UTF-8 input.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{\encodingdefault}{i}{\={\i}}

\begin{document}

\={i} or ī

\end{document}
```

The `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand` is not required if you're able to directly input `ī`, but it doesn't hurt either.

[image]

On my system I get `ī` by the key combinations <kbd>Option+a</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> (pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> together with <kbd>a</kbd> is a dead key that will add a macron to the next typed letter).